# Confusion around Signing Mac App Installer

Tags: xcode, macos, installation

I'm having trouble understanding how to pack my Mac app into an installer (`.pkg`) and sign it for distribution **outside** of the App Store (e.g., my own website).

Xcode 6's Organizer/Archives window gives you four options to export a Mac app archive:

1. **Export a Developer ID-signed Application** - 
   Signing Identity: Developer ID Application:  (<10-digit Hex Number>)
2. **Save for Mac App Store Deployment** - Signing Identity: 3rd Party Mac Developer Application  (<10-digit Hex Number>)
3. **Export as a Mac Installer Package** Signing Identity: 3rd Party Mac Developer Application  (<10-digit Hex Number>)
4. **Export as a Mac Application** - (Prompts for save location right away)

Note how the option than exports an installer package does not use the "3rd Party Mac Developer **Installer**" identity (which certificate I also have in my Keychain), but the "3rd Party Mac Developer **Application**" signing identity. Why is that? Perhaps what is being signed here is the app contained in the installer, and I still have to sign the package itself? (By the way, I tried this but after sending the pkg to myself by e-mail, but on double click it yields the dreaded "can't be opened because it's from an unidentified developer" warning)

Apple's documentation is a bit terse, covers a lot of ground (signing bundles, executables, frameworks etc.) and seems centered around the command line tools `codesign` and `productsign`; the same can be said of related questions here in S.O. So, what is the purpose of Organizer's export option #3 listed above, then? Can I use it? Should I build the package using the command line, or can I leverage this Xcode/GUI tool and just sign the exported `.pkg` afterwards? (using the command line, I guess).

Why can't Xcode "just work", and pack/sign the app/package all in one go? My installer doesn't require any fancy logic or lays out any supporting files/directory structure; it's just a "wrapper" around my `.app`.

**ADDENDUM:** I instead tried exporting an `.app` bundle from Organizer, signed as "Developer ID Application" (Option #1 above), pack it with the old PackageMaker.app, and signing that using the command line. But I still get the "Unknown developer" error and can't open the installer after quarantine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly me; I was using the bogus certificate name "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: (My Name)" instead of "Developer ID Installer: (My Name)".

A quick test using:

`spctl --assess --type install <packagename>.pkg`

gives:

`<packagename>.pkg: rejected`

...which means that the package wasn't signed correctly for running as an installer I guess.

After fixing the identity name, and signing the `.pkg` file (built with either PackageMaker or Xcode) using:

`productsign --sign "Developer ID Installer <MyName>" ./Unsigned.pkg ./Signed.pkg`

, the `spctl` command runs silent (no feedback - success?), and if I send the resulting packages to myself via e-mail, and download them (quarantine), the installers will launch and install the app without issue.

**EDIT:** I will wait a couple of days before accepting my own answer, in case someone shares further knowledge.tips.

Comment: But seriously, Xcode should sign the package as well as the contained binary.